# Errors using a list of integers (Python + Google Ads API)

Tags: python, google-ads-api

I have a list of IDs that are integers. If I do `print(data_clients["id"])` I get something like:

```
4323324234
2342342344
5464564565
```

Then I want to call an API (Google Ads) that uses those numbers as IDs (to know which data to retrieve). I have to do a loop (or something similar) to get the data from each ID.

I've tried this

```
for id in range(data_clients["id"]):

                query = (f''' WHATEVER ''')
                stream = ga_service.search_stream(customer_id = data_clients["id"], query=query)
                list_id = []
```

With this code I get the following error:

```
4323324234 has type int, but expected one of: bytes, unicode
```

And if I try to convert the int to Unicode or bytes (with chr or to_bytes), I get

```
int too big to convert
```

Maybe the solution is obvious, but I'm a Python/coding beginner, so I'm pretty confused.

Any ideas? Thanks!

Comment: I don't think you want to use `range()` here.  In fact, if `data_clients["id"]` is a list as you say, then `range(data_clients["id"])` should have thrown an error, because you can't call `range()` on a list.

Comment: Show us the output of these: `print(type(data_clients["id"]))` and `print(repr(data_clients["id"]))`

Comment: `print(type(data_clients["id"]))` returns a list of <class 'int'>
<class 'int'>
<class 'int'> ...

Comment: `print(repr(data_clients["id"]))` gives the list of numbers that I mentioned in my original message: 4323324234
2342342344
5464564565 ...

Comment: I tried using range because the for loop without the range gave me an error (`'int' object is not iterable`) and some tutorials suggested using that "solution".

Comment: I don't see how `print(type(data_clients["id"]))` would print a list of types.  If that data item is a list, then it should print `<class 'list'>` exactly once.  It wouldn't print the types of the items _inside_ the list.

Comment: @JohnGordon OK, I think `data_clients` is a dictionary, not a list as I've said. But I think that everything else I mentioned still applies (`data_clients["id"]` gives me the numbers/IDs that I mentioned and I want to use those IDs inside a loop, but it gives me errors). Can you give me a solution or at least some ideas to solve my problem? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Assuming `data_clients["id"]` is a list of customer IDs, this should work:

```
for cust_id in data_clients["id"]:
    query = (f''' WHATEVER ''')
    stream = ga_service.search_stream(customer_id=cust_id, query=query)
```

Comment: It gives me the error `'int' object is not iterable` for the line `for cust_id in data_clients["id"]:`. I guess it's the same problem I mentioned in one of my previous comments (the ID numbers inside `data_clients["id"]` are integers so they can't be in a loop).

Comment: If you're getting the error `'int' object is not iterable`, then that means `data_clients["id"]` is a single integer.  There aren't any integers "inside" of it.  But yet when I asked you to show the output of `print(type(data_clients["id"]))`, you said it printed "a list".  I don't see how both of these things can be true.  You must be wrong about one of them.

Comment: OK, maybe I used the wrong word (I'm a Python newbie and English is not my first language). `print(type(data_clients["id"]))` gave me an output me several items, one after another, in different lines. I referred to that as a list, but I wasn't talking about a Python list (I'm still not sure what is the correct Python term for that).

Comment: Anyway, here is more data, in case it helps. If I do `print(data_clients)` I get: `{'descriptive_name': 'name1', 'id': 4323324234, 'status': 'ENABLED'}
{'descriptive_name': 'name2', 'id': 2342342344, 'status': 'ENABLED'}
{'descriptive_name': 'name3', 'id': 5464564565, 'status': 'ENABLED'}` (each in a different line)

Comment: And if I do `print(data_clients["id"])` I get what I mentioned in my original message (`4323324234
2342342344
5464564565`, each in a different line). I would like to use those numbers as the customer_id, to send 1 query for each of those customers (so 3 different queries for those 3 numbers in that example).

Comment: I'm still confused why `print(type(data_clients["id"]))` would print more than one thing.  Can you show the exact output of that statement?

Comment: I've already included that output before. I've managed to solve my problem going through a different path, because this one didn't seem near a solution. Thanks for your help anyway!